# Changing a test XML response into a Bean response Java

Tags: java, xml, javabeans, xmldocument, xmlnode

I am working on this test class and trying to change the response expected to a bean response as I have changed the requests to bean requests.

```
private void assertXmlResponse(Document xmlResponse, int Elements,
            String Message, String Code, String name,
            String Funds)
{
    Node topLevelElement = xmlResponse.getFirstChild();
    NodeList childElements = topLevelElement.getChildNodes();

    assertEquals("result", topLevelElement.getNodeName());
    assertEquals(Elements, childElements.getLength());

    assertEquals("message", childElements.item(0).getNodeName());
    assertEquals(Message, childElements.item(0).getTextContent());

    assertEquals("code", childElements.item(1).getNodeName());
    assertEquals(Code, childElements.item(1).getTextContent());

    assertEquals("name", childElements.item(2).getNodeName());
    assertEquals(name, childElements.item(2).getTextContent());
}
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction or even let me know if it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: Define a class with the expected response as attributes

Comment: @pd30 Thanks but I was looking for more syntax specific as I haven't worked with beans before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are about to make POJO(Plain Old Java Objects).

```
     public Class A{
      private int Elements; 
      private String Message;
      private String Funds;
      private String code;
      private String name;
      //getters and setters



       }
```

Keep the reference of this class as Parameter in your method.

Use the getters for accessing the value in your method.

Comment: Thanks, having a little trouble understanding. I can make the objects and set and get methods. But how would I then be able to put this as it is written above such as:  assertEquals("result", topLevelElement.getNodeName()); as these get picked from what I pass through my tests?
    assertEquals(Elements, childElements.getLength());

Comment: Suppose x is object of class A,then in your assertEquals(x.getMessage(),childElements.item(0).getTextContent())

Comment: childElements comes from the Node interface so throws an error at this point as we are not using Nodes. Not sure what to do at this point I have created them as objects and set them before executing assertEquals(x.getMessage(),childElements.item(0).getTextContent())

Comment: So get the elements from Node interface and treat them as actual response whereas the object you created and set all the properties is the expected response.Thats it